# How to check directory is existed before creating a new directory in JSCH

Tags: java, directory, jsch

How to check the existence of the  directory before creating a new directory using JSCH SFTP API? I am trying to use `lstat` but not sure it's doing the job that I need.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In situations like this it is always better to just do the create and handle the error. That way the operation is atomic, and in the case of SSH you also save a lot of network traffic. If you do the test first, there is then a timing window during which the situation may change, and you have to handle error results anyway.

Comment: But I can create the directory only one time.After that when user uploads the file to our application to that directory I have to check whether directory is existed.So, is there any alternate to do that?

Comment: @Srinivas Of course you can only create it one time. After that you will get an error. Handle it. As I said above.

Comment: Yeah got it.Thanks I didn't understand that eariler.Now it's clear thanks.

Answer (score 18):

This is how I check directory existence in [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

Create directory if dir does ont exist

```
ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
String currentDirectory=channelSftp.pwd();
String dir="abc";
SftpATTRS attrs=null;
try {
    attrs = channelSftp.stat(currentDirectory+"/"+dir);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(currentDirectory+"/"+dir+" not found");
}

if (attrs != null) {
    System.out.println("Directory exists IsDir="+attrs.isDir());
} else {
    System.out.println("Creating dir "+dir);
    channelSftp.mkdir(dir);
}
```

Comment: Af for as I remember that `attrs` won't be null when it doesn't find a directory. It throws an exception.

Comment: @SRy: yes but I have assigned null to it while declaring, so if the exception is not thrown `attrs` value would not be null

Comment: I don't think your code works as you expected. Cause when an exception is thrown in the above code when no directory exists you assuming control will come to `else` block,there is no chance that control comes to `If-else` block. So your code only works when `attrs` not nul

Comment: Exception will be thrown in "attrs = channelSftp.stat(currentDirectory+"/"+dir);" line which is under a try catch block. later it will proceed to if else part. if attrs value did not change (which is null) then it will go to else part and create directory

Comment: yeah I am sorry , you are correct. Morning man . I need some coffee.I was not thinking properly about exception

Comment: That's fine. It's night here just used this to fix my problem :)

Comment: I think Exception is to eager, it can be more specific: 
`try{`
`   channel.stat(folderName);`
`}`
`catch (SftpException e ){`
`   if (e.id == ChannelSftp.SSH_FX_NO_SUCH_FILE ){`
`      channel.mkdir(folderName);`
`   }`
`   else {`
`      throw e;`
`   }`
`}`

Answer (score 5):

I am repeating the same answer here in the broader context. The particular lines to check if the directory exists and make a new directory  is

```
            SftpATTRS attrs;
            try {
                attrs = channel.stat(localChildFile.getName());
            }catch (Exception e) {
                channel.mkdir(localChildFile.getName());
            }
```

Note. the `localChildFile.getName()` is the directory name that you want to check. The whole class is attached below that sends a file or content of a directory recursively to the remote server.

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.*;

/**
 * Created by krishna on 29/03/2016.
 */
public class SftpLoader {
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SftpLoader.class.getName());

ChannelSftp channel;
String host;
int    port;
String userName ;
String password ;
String privateKey ;


public SftpLoader(String host, int port, String userName, String password, String privateKey) throws JSchException {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
    this.privateKey = privateKey;
    channel = connect();
}

private ChannelSftp connect() throws JSchException {
    log.trace("connecting ...");

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(userName,host,port);
    session.setPassword(password);
    jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();
    log.trace("connected !!!");
    return (ChannelSftp)channel;
}

public void transferDirToRemote(String localDir, String remoteDir) throws SftpException, FileNotFoundException {
    log.trace("local dir: " + localDir + ", remote dir: " + remoteDir);

    File localFile = new File(localDir);
    channel.cd(remoteDir);

    // for each file  in local dir
    for (File localChildFile: localFile.listFiles()) {

        // if file is not dir copy file
        if (localChildFile.isFile()) {
           log.trace("file : " + localChildFile.getName());
            transferFileToRemote(localChildFile.getAbsolutePath(),remoteDir);

        } // if file is dir
        else if(localChildFile.isDirectory()) {

            // mkdir  the remote
            SftpATTRS attrs;
            try {
                attrs = channel.stat(localChildFile.getName());
            }catch (Exception e) {
                channel.mkdir(localChildFile.getName());
            }

            log.trace("dir: " + localChildFile.getName());

            // repeat (recursive)
            transferDirToRemote(localChildFile.getAbsolutePath(), remoteDir + "/" + localChildFile.getName());
            channel.cd("..");
        }
    }

}

 public void transferFileToRemote(String localFile, String remoteDir) throws SftpException, FileNotFoundException {
   channel.cd(remoteDir);
   channel.put(new FileInputStream(new File(localFile)), new File(localFile).getName(), ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);
}


public void transferToLocal(String remoteDir, String remoteFile, String localDir) throws SftpException, IOException {
    channel.cd(remoteDir);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(channel.get(remoteFile));

    File newFile = new File(localDir);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);

    log.trace("writing files ...");
    int readCount;
    while( (readCount = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        bos.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
    }
    log.trace("completed !!!");
    bis.close();
    bos.close();
}
```